# Produce leading zero with NSNumberFormatter for Currency

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

for number, after formatting, I hope it show as $050, below code does not work. But If I use NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle, it can show 050. Do you know why?

```
    NSNumberFormatter *f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] ;
    f.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterNoStyle;

    NSNumber *myNumber;
    NSString *myString;     

    myNumber = [f numberFromString:@"50"]; // Note that the extra zeros are useless
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyAccountingStyle];
    [f setFormatWidth:3];
    //[f setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadAfterPrefix];
    [f setPaddingCharacter:@"0"];
    myString = [f stringFromNumber:myNumber];
    NSLog(@"myString: %@",myString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boring answer is that US currency style (and Australian and Canadian, as far as I know) never uses leading zeroes, unless the amount is zero dollars and some cents (e.g. "$0.43"). The `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`, on the other hand, *can* use padding zeroes.